# AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Surname'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to create a blog/booking website, and I'm trying to save all the customer accounts to a database. I'm following COdemy's Flask Friday videos, but for some reason when I try and create the variable 'our_users', and set it to query my database and order it by surname, it gives me the error AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Surname'. Here's the relevant code.

```
class Customers(customers_db.Model):
id = customers_db.Column(customers_db.Integer, primary_key=True)
FirstName = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(100), nullable=False)
Surname = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(100), nullable=False)
Email = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(120), nullable=False, unique=True)
Age = customers_db.Column(customers_db.Integer, nullable=False)
Gender = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(10), nullable=False)
Nationality = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(20), nullable=False)
#custpass_hash = customers_db.Column(customers_db.String(120), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Name %r>' % self.Surname
```

that's my model

```
class ConsultantSignUp(FlaskForm):
firstname = StringField("First Name:", validators=[DataRequired()])
surname = StringField("Surname:", validators=[DataRequired()])
title = StringField("Title:", validators=[DataRequired()])
email = StringField("Email:", validators=[DataRequired()])
age = StringField("Age:", validators=[DataRequired()])
gender = StringField("Gender:", validators=[DataRequired()])
years_of_experience = StringField("Years of Experience:", validators=[DataRequired()])
#password = String
#passwordconfirmation =

submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

this is my form

```
  @medcity.route('/cust_signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

  def cust_signup():
      form = CustomerSignUp()
      FirstName = None
      Surname = None
      Email = None
      Age = None
      Gender = None
      Nationality = None



if form.validate_on_submit():
    customer = customers_db.query.filter_by(Email=form.Email.data).first()
    if customer is None:
        customer = Customers(
        FirstName = form.FirstName.data,
        Surname = form.Surname.data,
        Email = form.Email.data,
        Age = form.Age.data,
        Gender = form.Gender.data,
        Nationality = form.Nationality.data)
        
        customers_db.session.add(customer)
        customers_db.session.commit()

    FirstName = form.FirstName.data
    form.FirstName.data = ''
    Surname = form.Surname.data
    form.Surname.data = '' 
    Email = form.Email.data 
    form.Email.data = ''
    Age = form.Age.data 
    form.Age.data = ''
    Gender = form.Gender.data 
    form.Gender.data = ''
    Nationality = form.Nationality.data 
    form.Nationality.data = ''
        
    flash("Sign Up Succesful!")

our_customers = Customers.query.order_by(customers_db.Surname).first()

return render_template('cust_signup.html',
    form = form,
    FirstName = FirstName,
    Surname = Surname,
    Email = Email,
    Age = Age,
    Gender = Gender,
    Nationality = Nationality)
```

and thats me putting it on the page.
This is my .py file

Any help would be appreciated!!
The page works and everything and all the indentations are fine idk why but it should be indented correctly from "if validate on submit" ... I can't fix it. Pls lmk if you need more code!!

Comment: `our_customers = Customers.query.order_by(customers_db.Surname).first()` should be `our_customers = Customers.query.order_by(Customers.Surname).first()`.

Comment: I tried that but when I write that, I get an error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: customers
[SQL: SELECT customers.id AS customers_id, customers."FirstName" AS "customers_FirstName", customers."Surname" AS "customers_Surname", customers."Email" AS "customers_Email", customers."Age" AS "customers_Age", customers."Gender" AS "customers_Gender", customers."Nationality" AS "customers_Nationality" 
FROM customers ORDER BY customers."Surname"
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (1, 0)]

Comment: if I keep it how it is in the code, it seems to read that line and give me the attribute error instead

Comment: `no such table: customers` -> you need to create your tables by running `db.create_all()` after all the models have been defined.  You might need to watch your videos again, or read the official flask-sqlalchemy documents.

Comment: I tried doing that just now but got this error: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'consultants_db' from 'medcity' (D:\MedCity_ia\m
edcity.py)